# PHP read text from textarea, use convert_uuencode and write it to another textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, c

As i wrote in the title i need to read text, that user would input into textarea and the encode it with convert_uuencode and then write it to another textarea.

I need this for school

Right now it looks like this:

```
<?php
$niz = $_POST['input']);
echo $niz;
echo convert_uuencode($niz);
?>
```

Post read from textarea with ID input

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>PHP vaja</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style/type="text/css">  
body {  background-color:#99b3ff;}
.wrapper {    text-align: center;}
.knof {    position: absolute;    top: 50%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

Input:<br />
<textarea rows="7" cols="100" id="input" name="input">
Please input a message! 
</textarea>

<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="select" value="Encrypt the text"     onclick="select()"/>
<br /><br />

<?php
function code(){
$niz = $_POST['input'];
echo $niz;
echo convert_uuencode($niz);
}
?>

<br />Output:<br />
<textarea rows="7" cols="100" id="output" name="output">
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the late post of the code, it was a bit messed up. For now it should only write out the encrypted message, later i will write it in textarea.

Comment: Should've started on your assignment earlier....

Comment: If you want to read with PHP, then you will use $_POST or $_GET, right?

Comment: I know. I just dont know how to do this, everything else is no problem.

Comment: Sorry you are in a bind, but SO is not the place to get schoolwork done for you, we are glad to help if you show an initial effort, i.e. existing code, what you have tried, and why it doesn't work for you or what errors it throws.... and as soon as I type this you edit your post lol.

Comment: So whats wrong? Looks good.

Comment: When pressing  `<input type="submit" name="select" value="Use function" onclick="select()"/>` the following function should be called but nothing happens `<?php
function code(){
$niz = $_POST['input'];
echo $niz;
echo convert_uuencode($niz);
}
?>`

Comment: You are missing a lot of code to show us that then, we need to see the html source form and the complete php form handler

Comment: @Wobbles I had the code really messed up, so i edited it a little.

Comment: I will post the whole code in my question so it is more organized

Comment: You need to post both the HTML and PHP in your question. Please read: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I posted whole page. It is saved as a .php. There is a bit of javascript I didnt post, but it only writes current time. I will read it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112202/discussion-between-kristjan1215-and-wobbles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all, your really should ask questions which are meant to teach you something, but I wanted to help you anyway:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP vaja</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                background-color: #99b3ff;
            }
            .wrapper{
                text-align: center;
            }
            .knof{
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" target="_self">
            <label for="input">Input</label>
            <textarea rows="7" cols="100" id="input" name="input" placeholder="Pleas input a message!"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="encrypt">
        </form>

        <label for="input">Output</label>
        <textarea disabled rows="7" cols="100" id="output" name="output">
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['input'])){
                    echo convert_uuencode($_POST['input']);
                }
            ?>
        </textarea>     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works great. I did learn something. How to use $_POST and functions for php. Apreciated.

Comment: @Kristjan1215 No problem, my I ask for which class you needed this homework ?

Comment: RSA(razvoj spletnih aplikacij) - Web Application Development. In this class we learnt about html, css, javascript and php. I am finnishing 3+2 middle school in Slovenia. Next stop - IT colege.

Comment: @Kristjan1215 so this would be about the 8th grade ? I really don't know the slovenien  school system.

Comment: Im 20 years old. Here you finnish 9 years of basic school then you choose your proffesion. I choosed "computers". Then you can go trough 4 year system and become a "technitian" or take 3 year course to get a "profession". You can upgrade this with 2 more years to become a "technitian". After that you go to colege, if you wish. Colege is free here but many choose not to go (many do, obviously). This translations are far from perfect but it should do the trick.

Comment: @Kristjan1215 oh all right ! I wish you the best with your way :)